# Get substring between string and multiple parenthesis. C#

Tags: c#, regex, substring

I'm trying to get the values inside a parenthesis specifically "(Paternal)" or "(Maternal)" depends on my condition. However, I'm getting all the string after ")" after setting it as last index.

Below is my code I have so far.

```
String fammedhistory= "High Blood Pressure(Paternal), Reproductive Disease(Maternal)";
int From = fammedhistory.IndexOf("High Blood Pressue(") + "High Blood Pressue(".Length;
int To = fammedhistory.LastIndexOf(")");
String result = fammedhistory.Substring(From, To - From);
txthistory.Text += result;
```

Output: Paternal, Reproductive Disease(Maternal)

I only need: Paternal

Is there a way to stop on the first ")" after the IndexOf.

Comment: You should replace `fammedhistory.LastIndexOf(")");` with `fammedhistory.IndexOf(")",From );`

Comment: You should probably start by splitting it at the `', '` so you can treat the as individual blocks after that; you'll have `High Blood Pressure(Paternal)` and `Reproductive Disease(Maternal)`, this could make it more manageable, and also have intermediate steps at treating your strings instead of doing everything at once which will create a quite rigid system

Comment: Why are you using `LastIndexOf`?

Comment: Try this regular expression: "\(([^\)]+)\)" Between the qoutation marks

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya thanks for your answer. I got it now.